# Setting up Play Framework 2.5.x with Hibernate OGM Neo4j

Tags: jpa, playframework, neo4j, playframework-2.5, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to setup Hibernate OGM to work with Play Framework 2.5.x(17) in my case but I keep getting "Cannot connect to database [default]" error. Apparantly Play takes MySQL driver as default and I am not able to find a driver configuration specifically for Neo4J.
Here is my persistance.xml file content:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- Use Hib77ernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->

<provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                  value="JBossTS" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="neo4j_http"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost:7474"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="neo4j"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="neo4j"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And application.conf content:

```
 db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
    jpa{
      default=defaultPersistenceUnit
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "DefaultDS" ? because JPA defines that as a javax.sql.DataSource and I doubt that Neo4j does those ...

Comment: Apparantly DefaultDS is just a declaration(dummy) since jpa mandates it. Hibernate OGM will ignore it anyways.

Comment: Nope, JPA does not mandate a `non-jta-datasource`. And if you specify the "javax.persistence.jdbc.XXX` props it uses those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem then I found one solution that we can use neo4j jdbc driver.

application.conf :-

```
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS  
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit  
db.default.driver=org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver  
db.default.url="jdbc:neo4j:http://localhost"  
db.default.user= neo4j  
db.default.password="password"
```

persistence.xml

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>domain class name</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                  value="JBossTS" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="neo4j_http"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost:7474"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="neo4j"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="password"/>


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```